# Getting red underline error in Row when using "Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL"

Tags: apache-poi

When I trying to read data from excel I am getting red underline error in eclipse for "Row"[image: Row Error] in Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL . I am using mac system

code:
public static void setCellData(String Result, int rowNum, int colNum) throws Exception {

```
    try {

        xRow = ExcelWSheet.getRow(rowNum);


        cell = xRow.getCell(colNum, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);


        if (cell == null) {

            cell = xRow.createCell(colNum);

            cell.setCellValue(Result);

        } else {

            cell.setCellValue(Result);

        }
```

Comment: Which version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: Version: poi-bin-4.0.1

Comment: See the [Apache POI javadocs for 4.x - it's there](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html). Check you don't also accidentally have an older jar too!